# How do you test for a faulty PCB board other than continuity test?

Tags: pcb

I got this PCB and i am not sure how to find the fault. I tried checking for the conenctions and all seems to be connected. What other ways are there to test it for faults?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about the type of fault you're trying to find

Comment: Assume we know nothing or better assume you know nothing and read your question.  Do you think anyone would be able to provide a definitive answer from that. Tag doesn't even add anything!   Prototype pcb?  Populated?  Did it ever work?  And that is just scratching the surface!

Comment: Is it a supply fault or circuit fault?  Why did you assume the PCB was at fault?

Comment: Diode mode on your multimeter and check every semiconductor.

Comment: hi guys, sorry for the lack of information.  I got two same boards. I set the power supply to 13 V which is within the operating range. However when i plug in the non-working board, the voltage drop to 9V. I suspect that there maybe a faulty component. I also found burnt marking on a soldered shottky diode. The board is operating between 11v to 28V.

Comment: MUCH more information needed ir people will vite to close it. Photos should help. Lonks, descriptions, ... . If you have two identical then side by side test of voltages ar various points whould help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all most of the board are coming from the fabricator already tested. *Never* buy an untested board even if it's cheaper, you'll lose a lot of time testing afterward.

Assuming it's an homemade board, a PCB can only have two different faults:

- An overetched trace, i.e. an interrupted trace; you say you have to ruled out this
- An underetch, i.e. two adjacent traces shorted together. This is *extremely* painful to find

Inspect carefully (lens, microscope, put the board on a scanner) where the traces are going one near to another and test where you suspect the short is then *knife away* the excess copper.

To be 100% sure you'll need to test *every adjacent network* and that's what the automatic machine at the fabricator does (also the reason I said it's painful)